# Email form not sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to implement contact form to my website and it isn't working. I'm trying to do it by [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html) tutorial. I changed the $myemail variable to my email address and tried it out. I get the "thank you" message but the email never comes.

I also checked comments on this tutorial and some people are saying it works and some are saying it never sends an email. I also checked the code myself very carefully and as far as I know it SHOULD send the email.

It successfully gets email variables and uses them with:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

But why isn't it working?

Comment: my first stop in theses cases is the mail server log

Comment: There are at least a handful of factors that might be playing a role in whether or not the `mail()` function will send it. Are you using a shared web-hosting provider? If so, chances are mail is queued and won't be sent for roughly 20 minutes to an hour after the request to send the mail was sent, depending on the mail-server's current load. That's only one potential point of failure, assuming you're using a shared hosting environment. Ask your hosting provider if you can see the mail logs. Try doing `if (!mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) { print 'there was an error'; }`

Comment: Did you bother checking the return value of `mail()` to see if it failed? Did you bother checking your mail server's logs to see what happened **AFTER** php/mail finished their jobs? Remember that PHP/mail's SOLE job is to take your email (e.g. the envelope) and walk it down to the street corner and drop it into the mail box. There's absolutely no way to for php/mail to see what happens to your envelope after it's in the mailbox. maybe the mail truck never came. maybe the airplane it was on crashed and burned. maybe the receiver threw it in the trash (spam...).

Comment: my mail did not send, has been asked a million times, and really there are a a million possibilities

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention one **very** important detail since I didn't know how these things exactly work. I'm running the whole thing on USB Web Server. I'll try uploading it to a free webhost to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a Sample for `mail()` And Works good:

```
        $to ='Info@sample.com';
        $message = '<a>Hellow</a>';
        $subject ='Hello world';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <sender@email.com>" . "\r\n";
$mail_sent=@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo $mail_sent ? "Success" : "Error";
```

if this sample not working , Call to Your server Administrator For check Server...